# How to open safe wallet on CLI?

Tags: gnosis-safe, cli

I am a first time user of cli so bear with me - I am trying to open my optimism wallet using cli.

I am trying to use this command line: safe-cli <checksummed_safe_address> <ethereum_node_url>

I am putting in my optimism address within the first bracket and then 'https://mainnet-sequencer.optimism.io/' in the second bracket, but it doesnt work.

I have just tried doing this same command line with same info, but without the brackets and I get an error saying 'safe-cli' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable file.

Answer (score 0):

> not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable file

This seems to be a Windows message. If you are on Windows, you need to run install & run safe-cli in [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) (WSL).

Comment: I input this command and says that it is already installed. I tried it again after and still says safe-cli is unrecognisable.